# How to make a search function able to search two different type of data/item in one search bar

Tags: asp.net, search, asp.net-core-mvc

I have code to search the merchants, but I need it to be able to search using the category/subcategories

I have here is:

Category > as the (Food, Leisure, Services, etc.)
so I'll take Food Category for example

Subcategory > Desserts , Bakery, Coffee, Chinese Cuisine

and under each subcategories was the merchants

Sample:

```
Category(Food) > Subcat(Coffee) > Merchant(J.Co)
```

so I would just like to type Coffee and hit enter, and the list of merchants under Subcategory of Coffee should show up...

Any tips and tricks?

Thanks by the way.

```
var merchantList = [];

function PopulateMerchant() {
   merchantList = [];
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/Merchant/ActiveMerchants",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            if (data != null) {
                for (var a = 0; a <= data.length - 1; a++) {

                    var name = data[a]["name"];
                    var merId = data[a]["merchantId"];
                    var type = {
                        id: merId,
                        label: name
                    };

                    merchantList.push(type);
                }

            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    return merchantList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is going to depend on how you are organising your data on the back end and how you organise your search query on your data.

I'll assume you are using a stored procedure in a SQL database, however the same basis process would probably be workable on other data sources. Obviously I've made some assumptions about how your data is connected, but you can adjust to suit

This works based on having your search term to be used in a LIKE statement, so when you set the `@searchTerm` parameter you would set it to `"%{searchterm}%"` (with the `%` symbols)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoMerchantSearch
(
    @searchTerm nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

    Select merchant.*
    From merchant
        inner join subCategory on subcategory.id = merchant.subcategoryId
        inner join category on category.id = subcategory.categoryId
    Where merchant.enabled = 1
        and (merchant.name like @searchTerm
            or subCategory.name like @searchTerm
            or category.name like @searchTerm)

END
```

So if your search term was "Coffee", this would create an input parameter of "%Coffee%" and would match any category, sub-category or merchant that had "Coffee" in their name.

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Edit: Did forget to mention that you'd also need to ensure your javascript AJAX call was also passing the search term.